# Saving functions arguments in array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, menu, structure

I'm new to this forum. Very litlle programing experices. And english is not my primary language :)

I'm writing C code for microcontroller and for now I have created Graphic menu with array of structures. In this array I have defined jumps in case of pressed buttons (UP, DOWN, ENTER), menu texts  and called functions in case of pressed buttons (if you are on correct submenu you can call functions).

Structure definition:

```
typedef const struct Menu_structure
{
    const char *text;
    unsigned char Menu_points;
    unsigned char Menu_button_UP;
    unsigned char Menu_button_DOWN;
    unsigned char Menu_button_ENTER;
    Menu_Waveform_parameter_t Waveform_parameter_value;
    void (*Menu_function_UP) ();
    void (*Menu_function_DOWN) ();
    void (*Menu_function_ENTER) ();
} MenuEntry;
```

1:menu tekst, 2:size of current submenu(for refresh purposes), 3:jump in case of UP, 4: jump in case of down, 5: jump in case of enter, 6: parameter enum, 7: function that are called in case of presses buttons.

Example of array:

```
MenuEntry menu[] =
{
    {menu_01,   5,  0,  0,  0,  0,              0,  0,  0},         
    {menu_02,   5,  1,  2,  1,  0,              0,  0,  funtion_0}, 
    {menu_03,   5,  1,  3,  6,  0,              0,  0,  0},             
    {menu_04,   5,  2,  4,  11, 0,              0,  0,  0},             
    {menu_05,   5,  3,  4,  1,  0,              0,  0,  funtion_1},
 }
```

Code for calling function (enter button pressed)

```
        case Button_ENTER:      if (menu[Menu_selected].Menu_function_ENTER != 0)
                                {
                                    menu[Menu_selected].Menu_function_ENTER();
                                }
                                break;
```

Everything works perfectly. The problem is that my menu is very long. Which means that I would need a lot of different functions (some of them can be combined with use of arguments).

Here comes my question. How can I save constant arguments in a array of structures. Any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: this is not a forum.

Comment: Can you save them as global variables in your code which your other functions can access?

Comment: 1) SO is no consulting site. 2) use correct prototype-declarators for your functions, not K&R style. 3) If you need many functions, how do you think you can reduce the number of functions?

Comment: Sorry for mistakes. I will more carefully read the rules. With reducing the functions i mean that I make one fuction for changing one variable in argument i can define in which direction and for how much. I would like to avoid a lot of global variables because its hard to change code in the future.

Comment: How many arguments do you want? What type(s) shall they have?

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish what you are asking for, I would first recommend moving on from C to some higher level language, at least for your User Interface.  (The rest of your low-level stuff can remain in C.) Nowadays you can find high level languages even in embedded systems, complete with features for interfacing with C.

But let me guess, this is not an option for you.

So, the second thing I would recommend in order to accomplish what you are asking for is to use that *wonderfully terrible hack* of C known as preprocessor macros.

In C you can define a macro like this:

`#define MYMACRO(a,b,c,d,e,i) { a, b, c,  d,  e,  0,              0,  0,  i }`

So then your table looks as follows:

```
{
    MYMACRO( menu_01,   5,  0,  0,  0,  0},         
    MYMACRO( menu_02,   5,  1,  2,  1,  funtion_0}, 
    MYMACRO( menu_03,   5,  1,  3,  6,  0},             
    MYMACRO( menu_04,   5,  2,  4,  11, 0},             
    MYMACRO( menu_05,   5,  3,  4,  1,  funtion_1},
}
```

Of course, you can define various different versions of `MYMACRO` with different arguments, expanding to use different constants, etc.  Knock yourself out!

Comment: The C preprocessor is not fairly described as a hack, wonderful or otherwise, it's a fundamental part of the language.  C would hardly be C without it.  Every C programmer needs to embrace the preprocessor.  Hack may scare rookies away. :-)

Comment: @StephenG I am not sure whether to agree or to disagree.  I think it might be a good idea to instil a bit of awe and fear of the preprocessor to rookies, because yes, you can do awesome stuff with it, but also, you can blow your foot off with it.

Comment: I have been using some preprocessor function, but never on such scale. Usaly just #define macro number or ifdef. I will take a look what else can be accomplish with it.

Comment: @mike-nakis Perhaps instil some *respect* in rookies, rather than fear.  But it's something they need to be encouraged to exploit ( indeed, as you did ), because it's so useful.  Heck I even use the C preprocessor with Java sometimes.  TKos, I would encourage you to learn about macros in C.  They can be tricky, but you can do things you cannot do any other way.